# Unable to derive both calculated values together for two new properties added via spread operator

Tags: angular, spread

When two properties added via Spread operator have separately derived values
the second property derivation 'appears' to stops first. Adding second property with derived value added via spread operator breaks first property value

The second is added via a function which is working, it's just that it stops the first property value from being calculated. I have a feeling this is because it's a different process (so works on yet another copy of array?). cv19_actisus: OR subcode are derived, it's one or the other but not both, kind of?

Here's the (see the hello.component)

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/spread-operator-adds-2new-seperatly-derived-property-values)

If you comment out the `subcode: this.updateCovidSubcodeData(),` and replace it with `subcode: '',` then the `cv19_actisus: Math.round(res.attributes.cv19_acti * 1.33)` and if subcode has any static value e.g., it works, but if I try to assign a value to the subcode using `subcode: this.updateCovidSubcodeData()`

I do see the correct value for the subcode but nothing for the cv19_actisus

For a little context this is data from two separate endpoints, one I can control, the other I can't (3rd party), so the code is adding two new properties doing a calculation to assign a value to one of the properties and using the data from the other endpoint to assign a value to the second property (based on a matching key:value pair found in the payload from each endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications and I think it's working. Your design was very strange and ineffective, mapping and remapping what you already have and ignoring the useful stuff that was accessible without any helper codes. Here is the [result](https://stackblitz.com/edit/spread-operator-adds-2new-seperatly-derived-property-val-rdlwz2?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) but let's go step by step:

```
// First, let's chain those subscriptions since their results depend on each other
ngOnInit() {
  this.c19service.intCodes() // We'll get codes first
    .pipe(
      tap(covidCodes => (this.covidCodes = covidCodes)), // save them to private prop
      concatMap(() => this.c19service.getCovid19data()) // and call for features
    )
    .subscribe(
      featrues => this.onC19DataRetrieved(featrues), // let's work with features now
      error => (this.errorMessage = <any>error)
    );
}
```

As you can see it is better to actually chain those subscriptions since they depend on each other. In your case they were executed independently and that lead to the `forEach` error you might have seen in the log. You tried to loop the array that was not yet initialized because the second subscription (*in your case*) was not done yet.

Now mapping. That was the most ineffective part of your code. You ignored what you had and did some resources consuming mappings and loops that lead to nowhere.

```
onC19DataRetrieved(data: Feature[]) {
  console.log(this.covidCodes);
  this.covidCases = data["features"];
  this.filteredmCovid = this.covidCases;
  this.newShape = this.covidCases.map(res => ({
    attributes: {
      ...res.attributes,
      cv19_actisus: Math.round(res.attributes.cv19_acti * 1.33),
      // you are already in features loop, you have the access to codmun of current feature/person
      subcode: this.updateCovidSubcodeData(res.attributes.codmun) 
    }
  }));
  this.filteredmCovid = this.newShape;
}

updateCovidSubcodeData(codmun) {
  // Here, just find the codmun match. But codmun from person comes as number
  // and it's a string in codes array -> that's why I'm parsing it
  const code = this.covidCodes.find(code => parseInt(code.codmun) === codmun);
  // If there is no match, just return '-'
  return !!code ? code.subcode : "-";
}
```

As you can see most of your code was useless. As mentioned in comment, you already have what you are looking for while spreading the object so just send the `codmun` as a param to your function and you don't need to search for it again. And then instead of trying to assign the value to the object independently just return the value you want and assign it directly in the spread operator.